# App Id of sandboxed app for like button

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to add a like button to a page. I have an app set up, but it is sandboxed. If I init the api with the sandboxed app ID, will the like button still work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook Like functionality in your case is separate from the application in interest.

Like buttons can be linked to URLs or Pages without the requirement of a Facebook application. All referenced Likes, then, are passed over to the respective linked content and do not pass through an application to do so.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much. Can you tell me how I would do this without an app id? I was under the impression I needed the API in order to add 'like' functionality